# How to set origin of 3d model with gltf extention using aframe in simulation using html, css and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to set position and pivot property in javascript but nothing seems to work out. Actually for the 3d model I gave key events to rotate in x-axis, z-axis, so while rotating the whole 3d object is moving, I just want to tilt the 3d object to 45 deg x-axis without changing the position

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.